# How to check if object is null in Java?

Tags: java, exception, null

What is the best way to check if a position is occupied or not? I don't think I should be using "this==null"...

```
class Cell {
    int column;
    int row;
    char letter;

    public Cell(int column, int row, char letter) {
        super();
        this.column = column;
        this.row = row;
        this.letter = letter;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if (this==null) return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `this` can *never* be `null` because it points to the current object. You need some other way to indicate that the `Cell` is empty such as another variable (a boolean, maybe?)

Comment: Derek Greer, at http://lostechies.com/derekgreer/tag/tdd/, has a long set of examples on writing a tic-tac-toe game using TDD where he faces similar problems on how to render cells. However, it's in C#. I do recommend it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the `char` is the content of your `Cell` and you want to check if that content is `null`.

First, `this` cannot ever be `null`. `this` is the current object, and therefore is always exists.

You are using a `char` - as this is a primitive is also cannot be `null`. Change that to the object wrapper and check that for `null`

```
class Cell {

    int column;
    int row;
    Character letter;

    public Cell(int column, int row, Character letter) {
        this.column = column;
        this.row = row;
        this.letter = letter;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return letter == null;
    }
}
```

Another note is that the superclass constructor is always called by default, there is no reason to call `super()`.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any option if I'm not allowed to change letter's type ?

Comment: From [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909333/whats-the-default-value-of-char) the default value of `char` if `\u0000`, which isn't a printable character - you _could_ test for that. Not overly robust however.

Comment: I'm guessing you don't want to change from `char` to `Character` because you use primitive `char`s already in other code? You should be able to transparently switch to `Character` in the `Cell` class due to [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/autoboxing.html). So constructing a new `Cell` (like `Cell c = new Cell(2, 3, 'x');`) still works if `Cell` uses `Character` instead of `char`, and you can use the `null` check. Otherwise, you'll have to choose some default value for `letter` to check, probably `\u0000` as bmorris591 suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If the instance of an object *exists*, then it cannot be `null`! (as the comment of Code-Guru says). However, what you are trying to do is to check if the `letter` attribute of your object is (or is not) null.

Just as a suggestion, instead of using `char` as the type, use `Character`, which is the class that encapsulates the `char` type.

Your class then will may look like this:

```
class Cell {
    int column;
    int row;
    Character letter;

    public Cell(int column, int row, Character letter) {
        super();
        this.column = column;
        this.row = row;
        this.letter = letter; // This is an object, not a primitive type 
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if (letter==null) 
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` cannot be `null` because `this` is your instance of a `Cell`.
 Without changing `char` to `Character`:

```
class Cell {
    int column;
    int row;
    char letter;

    public Cell(int column, int row, char letter) {
        super();
        this.column = column;
        this.row = row;
        this.letter = letter;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return letter == 0;
    }
}
```