# What is the value of an empty cell in a char array (Java)?

Tags: java, arrays, char

Please consider this scenario:

```
char[] array = new char[4];
array[0] = 'a';
array[1] = '3';
array[3] = 'q';
```

As you can see, `array[2]` was never 'filled' with anything. What would be the value of `array[2]`?

What do I need to check for when iterating through a `char` array, looking for 'empty' cells?

Comment: System.out.println(array[2]);

Comment: Not sure if duplicate, but significant and related, at least: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909333/whats-the-default-value-of-char

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`array[2]` will be populated with the `null char literal`. The value of which is `\u0000`.

`char` is a primitive type. This means that it can never hold `null`, so like `int`, `double` and the rest, it needs some starting value. For `int` it's `0`, for `char` it's `\u0000`, which actually evaluates to `0`.

You can view the starting values for primitive types [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Comment: So in an integer array of size 2 if I fill one cell with integer 0 and leave the other blank....does it mean both have same values ? Since null for int is 0 too.

Comment: There is no `null` for any primitive types - there are default values that they get initialised to. If you set the first value in an array to 0 and leave the second, they will both have the same value. https://ideone.com/tB2NxQ

Answer (score 3):

The answer is: (char)0.

Default values for primitives are 0, 0.0f, 0.0 (double), (char)0 and false (for boolean).

Applies to arrays and single variables.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, `char[] array = new char[4];` will set all the memory associated to that array to zero. In this case therefore each element will have the value of the null character literal `'\0'`.

(This is not true for all languages, in C and C++, for example, the memory is unitialised and to access it before initialisation is, technically, undefined behaviour).

Comment: It's not "technically undefined behaviour", it's just undefined behaviour :-)  (and a very bad idea).

Answer (score 1):

Empty cells of the array will be always 0, becs the arrays are automatically initialized by 0 so it will be '0'

Answer (score 0):

Like others already said, the default value will be null '\u0000'.
If you try to print it out, it will be an empty value. (Meaning you can't see it)