# How to update a string on each iteration of for loop?

Tags: java

```
   String up="hello world";
    String end;
    String w;

    for(int i=0;i<up.length();i++){
      n=0;
        z=3;
        end="hello world";
        w=end.substring(n,z);

        end=end.replace(w,"");
        System.out.println(end);
    }
    System.out.println("-->");
```

Here i have this string up and i just want to replace each alphabet in string with "" and update the replaced string at the end of loop 
for example:
initially we have up="hello world" after first iteration i want it to be up="ello world"

Comment: convert the string to character array and do it.

Comment: Why C# tag? How it is related to it?

Comment: @thanga i have to do it with substring it is restriction...

Comment: @VeeraKannadiga answer in any (java or c#) will be useful for me..

Comment: The inside of your loop does the same in every iteration. The value of end is set to "hello world" every time it is entered and then the same operations are performed, regardless of what i is. The result is that you print out the same thing up.length() many times.

Comment: @Aziuth you mean i have to remove end="hello world" for inside of loop?

Comment: Sorry, but if you need to ask, then what you should do is reading some basic tutorials and doing some basic exercises. You lack in some fundamental understanding of how programs works. Don't want to offend you, sorry if this sounds harsh, but that's how it is.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something simple like:

```
String up="hello world";
String end;

for(int i=0;i<up.length();i++){
    end = up.Substring(i,up.length()-i);
    System.out.println(end);
}
System.out.println("-->");
```

Be sure to head to https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx and learn how all methods and parameters of String class work.

Comment: @Tom i am not mixing it. I need solution for this problem either in java or c#

Comment: @sam You aren't the author of this answer post, so I didn't wrote to you.

Comment: I am really sorry; for some reason I was thinking about this question as a c# question; the right way to use this is to replace " end = up.Substring(i,up.length()-i); " with " end = up.substring(i); "

Comment: It was a Java and C# question and OP said he accepts both, but you shouldn't mix your code blocks with Java and C#. If you want to answer for both languages, then use two seperate blocks.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is that you are assigning `end="hello world";` for each iteration, so `end` is reset each time.

One way of doing it would be like this:

```
String up = "hello world";

while (!up.isEmpty()) {
  up = up.substring(1);
  System.out.println(up);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with char Array

```
public class MultipleTry {

public static void main(String args[]){

    char c = '\0';
    String up="hello world";

    char[] charArray = up.toCharArray();


    for(int i=0 ; i<up.length();i++){

        charArray[i] = c;
        up = new String(charArray);
        System.out.println(up);
    }       
 }
```

}

If you have question about bellow line,

> char c = '\0';

[click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859934/char-initial-value-in-java) here to get more information